# How to parse a string of JSON that contains nested JSON strings (mixed single and double quotes)?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string of JSON that contains an array. The objects in the array have a property that has a string of JSON nested. The JSON string comes from another system and I don't have control over the format.

```json
[{'id': 702, 'data': '{"color":"red","age":"32"}'}, {'id': 850, 'data': '{"color":"blue","age":"25"}'}, {'id': 941, 'data': '{"color":"yellow","age":"12"}'}]
```

When I try to parse the string as-is, I get `unexpected character`, referring to the first single quote.

```js
const json = "[{'id': 702, 'data': '{"color":"red","age":"32"}'}, {'id': 850, 'data': '{"color":"blue","age":"25"}'}, {'id': 941, 'data': '{"color":"yellow","age":"12"}'}]"; //cannot change the json. This comes from another system

const arr = JSON.parse(json); //error here
```

I thought about replacing the single quotes with double quotes, but that would mess up the nested json in the `data` property. I'll bet there's some magical solution that's just keystrokes away.

Comment: The format is broken. Fix it on the end that's generating it instead.

Comment: That isn't JSON. It's another data serialisation that seems to be based on a subset JS literal syntax but not the same subset as JSON uses.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the vocabulary! The system that generates this is Postgres using the `json_agg(t)` function. If I had another way to export json from a record set, I'd be in business.

Comment: I appreciate the comments so far, but unless I have another way to export correctly formatted "JSON" from Postgres using a SELECT query, then I go back to one of my statements in the question: "I don't have control over the format." Are there solutions?

Comment: You could try replacing the double quotes with a placeholder such as `~!~` then replace the single with double quotes, then replace the placeholders with single quotes. Then maybe it will `.parse`

Comment: The nested JSON is valid JSON, the problem is the outer string. I doubt that's coming from `json_agg()`.

Comment: @Barmar the nested JSON is a stringified JS object that I inserted into the db. The output you see is definitely from `json_agg()` but maybe the psql function is using single quotes because it detects double quotes in the json column?

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, nested double quotes are escaped in JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the double quotes with a placeholder such as ~!~ then replace the single with double quotes, then replace the placeholders with single quotes.

```js
const json = "[{'id': 702, 'data': '{\"color\":\"red\",\"age\":\"32\"}'}, {'id': 850, 'data': '{\"color\":\"blue\",\"age\":\"25\"}'}, {'id': 941, 'data': '{\"color\":\"yellow\",\"age\":\"12\"}'}]"; 

let temp = json.replace(/"/g, '~!~');
temp = temp.replace(/'/g, '"');
temp = temp.replace(/~!~/g, "'");

console.log(temp);
const arr = JSON.parse(temp); 

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a regex to pick out the objects in the array,

JSON uses double-quotes (`"`) for its strings, I replaced the keys with single-quotes with double-quotes

Then removed the quotes around the curly braces(`{}`)

```js
const data = `[{'id': 702, 'data': '{"color":"red","age":"32"}'}, {'id': 850, 'data': '{"color":"blue","age":"25"}'}, {'id': 941, 'data': '{"color":"yellow","age":"12"}'}]`;

const objectRegex = /(\{(.*?)(\}('|")\}))/g;

const object = data.match(objectRegex).map(match => JSON.parse(match.replace(/'(.*?)':/g, '"$1":').replace(/'{/g, '{').replace(/\}'/g, '}')));

console.log(object);
```